What is the failure mode of fiberglass rods in bending?
I have access to a bunch of used FRP rods, 1" in diameter x 40 feet long with metal ends.
I do not know yet if the plastic part is conventional polyester resin or nylon.
In normal use these rods are subject to high tension, and low bending stresses. (Wells are not as straight as illustrations in books would indicate, but the curve radius is large.)
I want to repurpose thse as shelter frames.  This will involve putting about a 45 degree arc on a 40 foot bar.  This puts the outside of the bar in tension.
A:  If I know then general PSI regime of these in use, and the modulus of elaticity, can I calculate the degree of curvature before failure.  Yeah.  Used material., big safety margins.  But being able to to a rough figure can determine if I'm wasting my time, or if I just jsut turn them into fence posts.
B:  What failure modes can I expect?  I think they will crack from the outside, straighten abrubtly with a kink at the crack point, until the remaining material can bend sufficiently.  But then I had a real WTF moment the first time I saw tempered glass explode.  I'd really like to not collect a darwin award.

Put on some protective gear and test them. Old poles like that cannot be predicted as they may have suffered damage you don't see or feel.

If you were to model it like any other composite, you'd probably treat it as layers of different materials that induce loads on one another to maintain the same node deflections as well as bear the overall loads. Exceeding the stress at which either material fails or their bond becomes undone becomes the failure criteria. Simplifying it for an analytical approach might involve figuring out how the combined material would deflect and then trying to solve for whether the parts might fail given that strain.

You can also get a local buckling failure in compression on the inside of the bend. Are these tow fibres or short lengths?
